# Firefox OS - Change screen brightness from privileged app

Tags: firefox-os

I'm trying to make a simple flashlight application for FirefoxOS. I need to set screen brightness to high level but according to [MDN][1]

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Settings_list only certified apps can change these settings.

So is it possible to write a certified application and published it? Or can I change screen brightness in privileged mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it possible to write a certified application and published it?

Unfortunately not.

See the section in [packaged apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Publishing/Packaged_apps) about certified apps. Apps published to the firefox marketplace can be privileged but not certified. For more information about the privileges marketplace apps can get, see [app permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/App_permissions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FApps%2FApp_permissions).